# Thread safety while inserting values in hashmap in parallel stream

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I need to make async calls with a timeout of 10 seconds, and need to perform this for every element from a map. The results of the async calls are stored in another map. Is it safe to use a `HashMap` in this case or do I need to use `ConcurrentMap`?

```
Map<String, String> x = ArrayListMultimap.create();
Map<String, Boolean> value = Maps.newHashMap();

x.keySet().paralleStream().forEach(req -> {
   try {
      Response response = getResponseForRequest(req);
      value.put(req, response.getTitle());
   } catch(TimeoutException e) {
      value.put(req, null);
   }
}
```

Is this thread safe? I'm not able to figure out. I know the alternative way is to create a concurrent hashmap, and think of some other filler value instead of null as Concurrent maps dont support null values.

Comment: Is your `Map` implementation thread safe?

Comment: @Flown Updated question. Added my map implementation type

Comment: So you're using a **non-threadsafe** map. What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` and return a map created with `Collectors.toMap()` terminating function instead of modifying external map in parallel. Consider following example:

```
Map result = x.keySet()
  .parallelStream()
  .map(req -> {
    try {
      Response response = getResponseForRequest(req);
      return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(req, response.getTitle());
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(req, null);
    }
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

In this example you return a `SimpleEntry` object that represents a key and value for each element and when all entries are processed you collect them to a single map.

#### Simplification

[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) suggested even more simplified solution by getting rid of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` at all:

```
Map result = x.keySet()
  .parallelStream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), req -> {
    try {
      Response response = getResponseForRequest(req);
      return response.getTitle()
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      return null
    }
  }));
```

Pick whatever works better for you.

Comment: Is there a way to return the values to 2 maps?